# Level set's matrix derivative.

Tags: calculus

1) consider the level set

$S=f^{-1}(0,1)=$ the set $[ (x,y,z) \in $$\mathbb  R^{3}$ such that $ (xy-yz=0) , (x^{2} + y^{2} +z ^{2}=1)]$

At which points on S is it possible to solve ( in their neighborhoods) for the variables x and z as functions of the variable y in the equations $ f(x,y,z)=(0,1)$,

ie, $(xy-yz=0)$ and $(x^{2} + y^{2} +z ^{2}=1)$

I don't really understand what a level set is, i know their neighborhoods means there is probably going to be some B(r,a) where $a  \in S$  but im not sure how to lay it out.

honestly i kind of want to think of this as as a plane with a directional vector.
anyone know where i can find some good illustrated examples ( preferably geometric pictures) as well as my question? as well how do u put set notation on the system?

Comment: I didn't quite get, your $f: \mathbb R^3\rightarrow\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Sorry that got copied from the notepad i typed the question out in its not part of this question.

Comment: Looks like so. Anyway, check my answer.

Comment: wow, so i can solve for x and z as functions of y inside of that ellipse on that line of intersection?

what did you use to graph that if u don't mind me asking?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following, I didn't use anything as a function of something. In other words, I have two equations. Each of them reveal some surface. Final answer, i.e. points, is intersection of those two surfaces. In your  case, first equation actually stands for two surfaces - 1) $y = 0$ and 2) $z=x$. I just substituted $y = 0$ and $z=x$ into the sphere equation one by one, each solution gave me one line. As for the software, I use Mathematica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, $S$ consists of all those $x,y,z$ points, where
$$
\left \{
\begin{array}{lcc}
xy-yz & = & 0 \\
x^2+y^2+z^2 & = & 1
\end{array}
\right .
$$
First equation has a solution
$$
\left [
\begin{array}{lcc}
y & = & 0 \\
x & = & z
\end{array}
\right .
$$
which looks like.

[image: x=z]

Second equation gives you points on unit sphere
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1
$$
So points, that satisfy both of those equations lie on intersection of this 3 surfaces.

[image: intersection]

which are vertical circle
$$
\left \{ \begin{array}{lcc}
x & = & \cos \phi \\
y & = & 0 \\
z & = & \sin \phi
\end{array}\right .
$$
and inclined ellipse
$$
\left \{ \begin{array}{lcc}
x & = & \frac 1{\sqrt 3}\cos \phi \\
y & = & \sin \phi \\
z & = & \frac 1{\sqrt 3}\cos \phi
\end{array}\right .
$$
In both cases $\phi \in \left [0, 2\pi \right )$, and both of them are obtained by simple substitution of $x=z$ and $y = 0$ conditions to the equation of sphere and applying polar coordinates. Level set look like

[image: levelset]